# Table like align input elements and labels

Tags: html, css

How could I align the following `input` elements for this `form` so that they resemble a table, with the labels on a top row and the `input` boxes on the bottom row, so that each `label` is above the corresponding `input` box, with the the arrow `button` in the left bottom corner of the form and the `plus` and `save` buttons in the bottom right corner? Also so that it can adjust gracefully to different screen sizes?

```
<body>
  <!-- Title & logo -->
  <div id="header">
    <h1><i class="fa fa-book"></i> loGym</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Main body of page -->
  <main role=”main”>
      <div id="description">
          <p>Fill in your workout and then click <i>Save Workout</i> when you are done.</p>
          <p>To add and extra column for reps and kg's, click the <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> sign on your screen.</p>
          <p>To add and extra row, click the <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> sign on your screen.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="workouts">
        <form id="workout-form">
              <label for="exercise" class="labels">Exercise</label><input type="text" id="exercise" placeholder="Which exercise?" autofocus />
              <label for="musclegroup" class="labels">Muscle-Group</label><input type="text" id="musclegroup" placeholder="Which muscle-group?" />

              <div id="sets">
                  <label for="reps" class="labels">Reps</label><input type="text" id="reps" class="reps-column" placeholder="How many reps?" />
                  <label for="kilos" class="labels">Kg's</label><input type="text" id="kilos" class="kilos-column" placeholder="How much Kg?" />
              </div>
              <button id="add-column"class="add-buttons" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></button>
              <button id="add-row" class="add-buttons" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-2x"></i></button>
              <button id="submit-workout" type="submit" name="submitbutton"><strong>Save Workout</strong></button>
        </form>
      </div>

  </main>

</body>
```

I have tried to use `float: left` and `clear` and change their `position` and `display` but they constantly overlap or are not in-line.

Comment: `...</label><br><input ... /><label><br><input...`

Comment: @MMRibot Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/s11610fz/

Comment: @avrilalejandro Adding a `<br>` doesnt solve the problem. It only messes-up the layout.

Comment: @MaryMelody thanks. Although that is not what I was aiming for in my description, its what I want once the screen size was mobile device size.

Comment: @MMRibot Please share your CSS code or try to make a fiddle demo, like this one - http://jsfiddle.net/s11610fz/

Comment: I erased my CSS because it was obviously failing and then posted the question.